Orthogonal Transformation of Hessenberg Matrices
$H\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an upper Hessenberg matrix. Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $H$ and $x$ is an eigenvector w.r.t. $\lambda$. Is there any fast algorithm that can find an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that
$$
Q^{\top}HQ=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda&w^{\top}\\&H_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $H_1\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}$ is also an upper Hessenberg matrix?
If take Householder transformation $H_0$ such that $H_0x=\|x\|_2e_1$, then $\|x\|_2H_0e_1=H_0^2x=x$ so the first column of $H_0$ is $\dfrac{x}{\|x\|_2}$. Thus, first column of $H_0^{\top}HH_0$ is $\lambda e_1$:
$$
H_0^{\top}HH_0=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda&w^{\top}\\&G
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then a sequence of Householder transformation can be used to make $G$ be an upper Hessenberg matrix. But this algorithm doesn't make full use of property that the original matrix $H$ is a Hessenberg matrix.
Any valuable advice is welcome!

use a sequence of planar rotations instead, they should preserve (more of) the structure

Thx! I have found an algorithm with complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

If you use Givens rotations, it should be possible to do this in O(n) time (if my memory isn't betraying me)

@AbdullahAliSivas no, there are n rotations, and each rotations requires approximately n flops. You may be thinking of symmetric matrices.

@AbdullahAliSivas Sorry, but can you give some details, please?

@ThijsSteel is right. I was not thinking of symmetric Hessenberg matrices, but I checked my lecture notes and my claim only holds symmetric Hessenberg matrices. Looking at the proof structural symmetry may be sufficient. For an upper  Hessenberg matrix it will $O(n^2)$. Apologies if I misled you MakaBaka

https://acme.byu.edu/0000017a-17ef-d8b9-adfe-77ef21120001/vol1a-qr1-decomposition-2016-pdf  I don't know if this link is going to survive but you can check "QR of a Hessenberg Matrix via Givens" for details.
